# Counting notes while metronome is playing

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

The following audio plays at `100` Beats Per Minute and a Time Signature of `4/4`.

The seconds and ticks being logged continuously grow in numbers. How can I determine:

- When the first measure is complete? i.e the second time `1` occurs ..  normally music is counted `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4`
- How can I determine when each quarter note occurs?

```js
(function() {
  var isPlaying = false;

  document.getElementById('togglePlayback').addEventListener('click', function() {
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 100;
    Tone.Transport.timeSignature = "4/4";
    console.log('Start playing');
    console.log(Tone.Transport.bpm.value);
    console.log(Tone.Transport.timeSignature);

    if(isPlaying) {
      Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(function(time){
        console.log('Seconds: ' + Tone.Transport.getSecondsAtTime(time));
        console.log('Ticks: ' + Tone.Transport.getTicksAtTime(time));
      }, "4n");
      Tone.Transport.start();
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/13.7.1/Tone.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="togglePlayback">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Your current code seems to work reasonably well. 100 bpm = 0.6 seconds per beat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a quarter note is 192 ticks, you can use that to determine the timing for other events and conditions:

```js
(function() {
  Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 100;
  Tone.Transport.timeSignature = "4/4";

  Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(function(time){
    console.log('Quarter Notes:', Tone.Transport.getTicksAtTime(time) / 192);
  }, "4n");

  var isPlaying = false;

  document.getElementById('togglePlayback').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      Tone.Transport.pause();
    } else {
      Tone.Transport.start();
    }

    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/13.7.1/Tone.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="togglePlayback">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

I've also revised your logic to play / pause instead of scheduling new repeats and starting from the beginning of playback on every second button press.

Comment: thanks for the added tip about how to schedule properly too +1